# JSF 2.0 Custom Validation problem

Tags: java, validation, jsf, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I want to validate the inputs to my JSF page inside my Managed bean, but for some reason it does not work?

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class RegistrationController {
//values passed from the JSF page
private String name; 
...
public void validateName(FacesContext context, UIComponent validate,
        Object value) {
    String inputFromField = (String) value;
    String simpleTextPatternText = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
    Pattern textPattern = null;
    Matcher nameMatcher = null;
    textPattern = Pattern.compile(simpleTextPatternText);
    nameMatcher = textPattern.matcher(getName());

    if (!nameMatcher.matches()) {
        ((UIInput) validate).setValid(false);
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                "your name cant contain special characters");
        context.addMessage(validate.getClientId(), msg);
    }
}
```

This is how input component looks like(Inside a form):

```
<h:inputText value="#{registrationController.name}" validator="#{registrationController.validateName}" required="true">
        <h:message for="nameInput"/>
```

When i enter a wrong input i dont see the validation message, and in the console i see this:

> INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
>   INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
>   sourceId=bRegForm:j_idt7[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(bRegForm:j_idt7: Validation Error: Value is required.), detail=(bRegForm:j_idt7: Validation Error: Value is required.)]

What it could be? Am i forgetting something? Do i have to add something to my configuration files...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to give your input component an `id`. That's where the `for` attribute of `<h:message>` should point to.

```
<h:inputText id="nameInput">
```

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, your approach is clumsy and technically wrong. As per the specification, you should throw a [`ValidatorException`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/ValidatorException.html). So instead of

```
((UIInput) validate).setValid(false);
context.addMessage(validate.getClientId(), msg);
```

do

```
throw new ValidatorException(msg);
```

Then JSF will worry about setting the component as invalid and adding the message to the context.

---

There's a second problem, you're validating the local value instead of the submitted value.

Replace

```
nameMatcher = textPattern.matcher(getName());
```

by

```
nameMatcher = textPattern.matcher(inputFromField);
```

Comment: I just did what you said but i dont see  any output in my form advicing me that i entered a wrong input. This is what the console says:INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=bRegForm:name[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(/WEB-INF/registerComposition.xhtml @14,132 validator="#{registrationController.validateName}": java.lang.NullPointerException), detail=(/WEB-INF/registerComposition.xhtml @14,132 validator="#{registrationController.validateName}": java.lang.NullPointerException)]

Comment: You **still** need to add `id="name"` to the input component. Then the `<h:message for="name">` can be found. I even said, **"Unrelated** to the concrete problem" :) By the way, you have introduced a new problem, a NPE.

Comment: I updated the answer. In the future, you should be asking a new question instead of reusing the same question for a different issue.

Comment: I just updated the post sorry. But i still see this in my console:INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=bRegForm:nameInput[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(bRegForm:nameInput: Validation Error: Value is required.), detail=(bRegForm:nameInput: Validation Error: Value is required.)]

Comment: Either the page is not republished to server, or you've a typo in `id` and `for` (it's case sensitive), or they are in a different page/scope. So for example putting input in a datatable and putting message outside datatable isn't going to work.

Comment: I see that typo, i now only call it name. But still says Validation Error: Value is required.) What that means? What value is required?

Comment: You've set it to `required="true"`. It's coming from JSF builtin validator. The field cannot be submitted empty. Enter something and your validator will be invoked. If you want to finetune the message, use `requiredMessage`. See also the bottom of this tutorial: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial i will read it carefully, but i think that required="true" makes no diference, becouse i add inputs like A,.3#$asdas and i still not see the message displayed. I checked a post in another blog where some guy says that the NullPointer has something to do with something about the JSF framework... http://www.nuwanbando.com/2008/01/validation-error-value-is-not-valid-famous-validation-error-when-using-custom-converters-in-jsf/ I tried to override equals in my Buyer entity, but still get:
...validator="#{registrationController.validateName}": java.lang.NullPointerException)]

Comment: Did you read the third part of my answer? With "there's a second problem". You've a bug in your code. You're validating the local value instead of the submitted value. The local value is `null`.

Comment: Yes i did. I am not validating the local value. I am using the submitted value. Maybe it has something to do with the regular expresion?

Comment: You have a bug in the code. Something is `null` while you're attempting to access/invoke it. Read the stacktrace in the logs until you find `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` and then trackback the 1st line in the code.

Comment: Ok i will try to find it in the logs. i see something is wrong becouse i never see the message NO MATCH!!! Ill will post latter when i find the solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You never see this message because the validator is never been past the bug. You need to fix the bug which is causing `NullPointerException`. And once again, please don't edit the question to fix the problems based on the answers. It makes the answers confusing and pointless to others. If you have a new problem, press `Ask Question` on right top.